# Cast list to numpy.array non-recursively

Tags: python, numpy

How can I create a numpy array from a list of objects without the objects in the list also being cast to numpy arrays?

```
import numpy as np
data = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
np.asarray(data)
```

Actual output:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Desired output:

```
array([list([1, 2]), list([3, 4]), list([5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

Numpy already does this for heterogeneous data:

```
>>> data = [[1, 2], [3], [5, 6]]
>>> np.asarray(data)
array([list([1, 2]), list([3]), list([5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

---

**Motivation**

As discussed in the comments, my actual objects do not naturally convert into arrays (as opposed to lists). The problem is that these objects still *do* provide an interface for conversion to `numpy` arrays, such that `np.asarray(obj)` returns a list of the attributes of `obj` and not a meaningful representation of the object itself.

The reason I would like to put the objects into a `numpy` array rather than a list is that these objects are best represented as a grid, and I need to be able to do slicing as well as custom reduction operations along arbitrary axes.

---

**Update**: One hack I found to achieve this is to make the array heterogenous, e.g.:

```
np.asarray(data + [None])[:-1]
```

I will accept any answer providing a cleaner solution.

Comment: What is the result of `np.array(data)`, possibly passing `dtype=object`?

Comment: I tried that as well, the result is always an `ndarray` of shape `(3, 2)`

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?  You won't get any of the benefits of `numpy` doing this.

Comment: @user3483203 As opposed to lists, my actual objects do not naturally convert into arrays. The problem is that these objects still *do* provide an interface for conversion to numpy arrays, such that `np.asarray(obj)` returns a list of the attributes of `obj` and not the object itself, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: I get that, I'm asking why you think it's better to have a `numpy` array of python objects as opposed to a list?

Comment: I see. My objects are best represented as a grid, and I need to be able to do slicing as well as custom reduction operations along arbitrary axes.

Comment: @jhansen, I don't have a solution, but you may wish to integrate your last comments in the question itself. I think it makes the question clearer and more interesting to future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cleanest, surest, way that I know of is - initialize and fill:

```
In [47]: arr = np.empty(3, object)                                                     
In [48]: arr                                                                           
Out[48]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [49]: arr[:] = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]                                             
In [50]: arr                                                                           
Out[50]: array([list([1, 2]), list([3, 4]), list([5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

Whether that's cleaner than `np.asarray(data + [None])[:-1]` is a matter of opinion.  In some cases I've also explored using `np.frompyfunc`, an iterator that returns object dtype array.

Error when trying fill the object array from a 2d array:

```
In [51]: arr[:] = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-d9f7715aecac> in <module>
----> 1 arr[:] = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,2) into shape (3)
```

but fill from a list of arrays works:

```
In [52]: arr[:] = list(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]))                             
In [53]: arr                                                                           
Out[53]: array([array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6])], dtype=object)
```